# Node js: Does res.locals get sent to client?

Tags: node.js, express

In Express, when I send a response back to the client, does the data in `res.locals` get sent back to the client?

I do not want that to be the case as I am storing sensitive data in `res.locals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. According to [the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals)

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the
> request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during
> that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this property is
> identical to app.locals.

Comment: I read that but did not understand the phrase "available only to the view(s)". What is a view?

Comment: the simplest answer is if you are setting `res.locals.isAuthenticated = ...` for each request, it means that data can only be accessed server side in Express. The only data that is sent is what you choose to send. The response is an http response, so there are default headers, etc.. but the default body is empty.

Comment: @michael_fortunato A view is a template. In MVC architectures views are code that generate the UI. For many web frameworks, since generating HTML from templates can be fully automated views are generally just templates

Answer (score 5):

`res.locals` is not sent to the client.

The purpose of `res.locals` is to create a standard place for server-side middleware to put data that is relevant to constructing the response.  This data is ONLY available server-side and is NOT automatically available to the client and is not sent with the response unless your code or template explicitly inserts some of that data into the web page.

The classic use for `res.locals` is when rendering templates because most template rendering engines will look in `res.locals` for properties that are referenced in the template.  So, your server-side code would set up some data in `res.locals` (usually standard data that applies to lots of templates) and then somewhere in a route handler, you call `res.render('sometemplate', ...)` and the template engine will look in `res.locals` for any variables that are specified in the template that were not directly passed as an argument to `res.render()`.  For example, some middleware might check to see if the user is logged in or not, set that state in `res.locals` and then the template can modify it's rendering based on whether they are logged in or not.